# What is the time complexity for deletion in singly and doubly linked lists?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, time-complexity, computer-science

If we don't know the position of the node, is it true that both singly linked list and doubly linked list take `O(n)` time to delete?

My understanding is that we need to traverse to node to know the previous pointer of the node and next pointer of node in singly linked list. The time complexity for singly linked list to delete is `O(n)` as a result.

For doubly linked list, since we know the previous and next pointers of the node we want to delete, the time complexity is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `O(n)` to *locate* a node in both cases (pseudo-code follows here, and in all cases below):

```
def locate(key):
    ptr = head
    while ptr != null:
        if ptr.key == key:
            return ptr
        ptr = ptr.next
    return null
```

---

It's `O(1)` to delete a node in a doubly linked list *given only its pointer,* because you can get to the previous node easily:

```
def del (ptr):
    if ptr == head: # head is special case
        head = ptr.next
        free ptr
        return

    ptr.prev.next = ptr.next
    free ptr
```

---

For those same conditions (only having the pointer), it's `O(n)` to delete a node in a *singly* linked list because you need to first locate the node *before* the one you want to delete:

```
def del (ptr):
    if ptr == head: # head is special case
        head = ptr.next
        free ptr
        return

    prev = head
    while prev.next != ptr:
        prev = prev.next
    prev.next = ptr.next
    free ptr
```

However, two `O(n)` operations is *still* `O(n)` since it's linearly dependent on the number of nodes.

Hence, to delete a node you don't yet have a pointer to, is `O(n)` in both cases, it's just the work done for each `n` would be bigger for the singly linked list, if you did it naively (as "locate node to delete" then "locate node before that one").

---

Typically though, you *wouldn't* do that. Your delete function would remember the previous node when advancing so that, once you'd found the one to delete, you also have the one before it so you wouldn't *need* another search.

That could go something like this, with us actually searching for the element *before* the one you want to delete:

```
def del (key):
    if head == null: # no action on empty list
        return

    if head.key == key: # head is special case
        temp = head
        head = head.next
        free temp
        return

    prev = head
    while prev.next != null:
        if prev.next.key == key:
            temp = prev.next
            prev.next = temp.next
            free temp
            return
        prev = prev.next
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answer, there is a way to delete a node from a singly linked list constant time given only a pointer to it if we allow the contents of a node to be moved. We would move the contents of the next node into the node to be deleted, and make the pointer to the next node point to the node after the next node.